# R matrix concatenate columns when matrix size is not known

Tags: r, matrix, concatenation

How can i concatenate all values in a row and create a vector?
I have provided my mat1 below and the expected outcome -vec1 is below that.

FYI: mat1 could have any number of rows and columns. I have provided 3*3 matrix just for example purposes

```
mat1=matrix(c(1:9),nrow=3)
vec1=c(147,258,369)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try one of the `apply` family functions and "paste" the rows and convert to "numeric"

```
 as.numeric(tapply(mat1, row(mat1), paste, collapse=''))
 #[1] 147 258 369
```

Or

```
 as.numeric(apply(mat1,1, paste,collapse=''))
 #[1] 147 258 369
```

Or convert the "matrix" to "data.frame" and use `do.call` to `paste` the rows

```
 as.numeric(do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(mat1), list(sep=''))))
 #[1] 147 258 369
```

Comment: Better to wrap in `as.numeric()` to match the expected output.